# Redirect to a laravel route with parameters through ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

On ajax success I have to redirect to a route in laravel. How do I do it???

I want the following to be done through ajax success function

```
return redirect()->route('unreconcil', ['cat' => $cat]);
```

Kindly Help...

Comment: Do you want the ajax request to be redirected or do you want the user to be redirect to a page once the ajax request is done ?

Answer (score 2):

Return the url back to the ajax success method

In your controller, return the path

```
return route('unreconcil', ['cat' => $cat]);
```

and in the success callback of your ajax method redirect using window location

```
success: function (data) {
    window.location = data;
}
```

Comment: It redirects me to the URL specified in the ajax URL for form submission.

Comment: It would redirect to whatever url that you'd return from your controller

Comment: Nope... It does redirect to the specified URL

Comment: What url are you returning from the controller?

Comment: I solved it... I just returned the parameter $cat value and used window.location = data.

Comment: Thanks for ur time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
return redirect()->route('unreconcil', ['cat' => $cat]);
```

try this:

```
return redirect()->route('unreconcil/'.$cat);
```

and your route should be like:

```
Route::get('unreconcil/{cat}',[
    'uses' => 'Controller@function'
]);
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: I want this to be implemented through jquery ajax... I have a form to be submitted through ajax.. after submitting the form on ajax success event I want to load the above route in ajax success... using windows.location.replace('route')

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/test', ['as'=>'testing',function(){
   return view('test');
}]);

Route::get('redirect',function(){

   return redirect()->route('testing');

});
```

Comment: I dont want any redirects through Laravel... 
I want the laravel route to be redirected through ajax

Comment: Further explanation on why this answer would work for the questioner or what may have been wrong in the original question would help raise the quality of this answer.